# Element fading in, but not fading out

Tags: javascript, css

I have the following javascript

```
function fadeIn(objectID, amount) {
object = document.getElementById(objectID + 'Des');
if(amount > 0)
{
    object.style.display ='block';
    object.style.opacity = '0';
}
var i = 0;
animatefadein = function()
{
    var MIN_OPACITY = 0;
    var MAX_OPACITY = 1;
    if ( (amount > 0 && object.style.opacity < MAX_OPACITY) || (amount < 0 && object.style.opacity > MIN_OPACITY)) 
    {
        var current = Number(object.style.opacity);
        var newopac = current + Number(amount);
        object.style.opacity = String(newopac);
        setTimeout('animatefadein()', 50);

    }

}
animatefadein();
if(amount < 0)
{
    object.style.display ='none';
}
```

}

I need to set display to none because on top of it another element needs to be placed if the user browses over them.

Here is the HTML,

```
<div id='products'>
            <img src = './product1.png' usemap='#ourProducts' alt='Our Products' title='Hover over the names to find out more.'>
            <map id='ourProducts' name='ourProducts'>
                <area shape='rect' coords="55,55,210,110" href='#' id='forcePort' alt='ForcePort' title='ForcePort' onmouseover='fadeIn("forcePort",0.1)' onmouseout='fadeIn("forcePort",-0.1)'/>
                <area shape='rect' coords="105,248,270,290" href='#' id='quickPort' alt='QuickPort' title='QuickPort' onmouseover='fadeIn("quickPort",0.1)' onmouseout='fadeIn("quickPort",-0.1)'/>
                <area shape='rect' coords="390,260,535,303" href='#' id='scrinter' alt='Scrinter' title='Scrinter' onmouseover='fadeIn("scrinter",0.1)' onmouseout='fadeIn("scrinter",-0.1)'/>
                <area shape='rect' coords="675,242,835,292" href='#'  id='bugTrail' alt='Bug Trail' title='Bug Trail' onmouseover='fadeIn("bugTrail",0.1)' onmouseout='fadeIn("bugTrail",-0.1)'/>
                <area shape='rect' coords="688,42,858,138" href='#' id='dataExtract' alt='CRM Data Extractor' title='CRM Data Extractor' onmouseover='fadeIn("dataExtract",0.1)' onmouseout='fadeIn("dataExtract",-0.1)'/>
            </map>
            <div id='productDes'>
                <div id='scrinterDes'>
                                      Data that needs to be shown!
                </div>
                <div id='bugTrailDes'>
                </div>
                <div id='quickPortDes'>
                </div>
                <div id='forcePortDes'>
                </div>
                <div id='dataExtractDes'>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

As you can see the fade out is not working. Also if you put a counter inside the setTimeout loop and print it to the console you'll see that it loops uncountable times on the fade out event. Here is the site in question,

[Website](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/14863356/OsmosysV3/index.html)

Just head over to products on the display, and hover over the product names.

Comment: Just asking: Why you don't use jQuery?

Comment: you tagged your question with `jquery` but don't seem to be using jQuery. If you are, you might want to look into `.fadeIn` and `.fadeOut` to take care of the animation.

Comment: put it on http://jsfiddle.net/ for a start

Comment: @MrOBrian I have never used jQuery before, but I'm open to using it. How much of a performance difference does it make? Also, in my case, wouldn't I have to set the display property to none or block before I start using fadeIn or fade out?

Comment: @AbijeetPatro: you will increase *developer performance* at least tenfold if you use jQuery instead of implementing your own (presumably cross-browser) animations etcetera =)

Comment: @Abijeet Patro so am I? it's not easy to understand what your code tries to accomplish just by looking to some pieces. It takes more time to put it up together than figuring the answer to the problem :)

Comment: @JoelPurra developer performance?

Comment: @AbijeetPatro: yes, the rate that you are producing results (for yourself or for a company) can be seen as a measurement of developer performance. For example, by writing these animation functions that someone else has written already (and spent a lot of time on making sure it works), you are reinventing the wheel when it's not necessary.

Comment: I included the jQuery API from google libraries, still nothing happens. I dont get any errors on chrome, opera just gives me a
Unhandled DOMException: SYNTAX_ERR. Here is the site updated:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/14863356/OsmosysV3/index.html

I used fadeIn and fadeOut like @Serj said

Comment: @AbijeetPatro: it looks like you're trying to load an insecure resource from a secure site. Change the jquery url to `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js` and you'll be fine.

Comment: @JoelPurra Fixed but still not working. also opera gives me a  Unhandled DOMException: SYNTAX_ERR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would hope that you realize that this is very easily accomplished with jQuery http://jquery.com/ The problem with your script is that `Opacity` and `Display` are two distinct CSS properties, to make this work, you'd need to set `Opacity` to 0, change `Display: none` to `block` or `inline-block` and then animate your `Opacity`

Comment: I am doing that aren't I? If I used jQuery wouldn't I still have to set the display to none or block?

Comment: No, jQuery automatically takes care of that for you, when you use the FadeIn, FadeOut functions

Comment: Tried it this morning, and it worked like a breeze! Thanks! Can you recommend a few more effects for images in jQuery?

It reduced my total js code by around 60 lines, which is a lot considering that I only had about 200.

Answer (score 1):

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/V8SAx/

First, you should never call `setTimeout` like this: `setTimeout('animatefadein()', 50)`, because it uses `eval`, which is very slow and insecure.

Second, here you have the code:

```
function fadeIn(objectID, amount,callback) {
    object = document.getElementById(objectID + 'Des');
    object.style.display ='block';
    object.style.opacity = String(Number(amount<0));
    animatefadein = function()
    {
        var MIN_OPACITY = 0;
        var MAX_OPACITY = 1;
        if ( (amount > 0 && object.style.opacity < MAX_OPACITY) ||
             (amount < 0 && object.style.opacity > MIN_OPACITY)
        ){
            var current = Number(object.style.opacity);
            var newopac = current + Number(amount);
            console.log(current + Number(amount));
            object.style.opacity = String(newopac);
            setTimeout(animatefadein, 50);

        }else{
            if(amount<0){object.style.display='none';}
            if(callback){callback();}
        }

    }
    animatefadein();
}
fadeIn('a',0.1,function(){fadeIn('a',-0.1);});
```

I have added support for a callback, which is called after the fading process, maybe it interests you.

Comment: I probably could make it work by fiddling around with this, but I think I'm going to check out the jQuery method for simplicity. You have my vote up :)